# How do I reference the component's instance of a NbWindow

Tags: angular, nebular

I want to do `child -> parent` communication using Nebular's NbWindow.

The method `windowService.open()` returns me a `windowRef`, but in this instance I can't find in any way my component's instance so I can subscribe to its event emitters.

I want to do something similar to what this github comment describe: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/3593#issuecomment-286397115

Answer (score 0):

windowService's `open()` method accepts a context object that can be injected in the target window component, so we can use it to make the components communicate.

```js
export class SearchWindowContext {
  onSearchFound = new EventEmitter();
}
```

```js
openSearchWindow() {
  const searchContext = new SearchWindowContext();
  searchContext.onSearchFound.subscribe(value => {
    console.log(`Searched valued: ${value}`);
  });

  this.windowService.open(
    SearchWindowComponent,

    {
      title: 'Window',
      context: searchContext,
    },
  );
}
```

Inside the component that is going to be opened:

```js
constructor(
  @Inject(NB_WINDOW_CONTEXT) private context: SearchWindowContext,
) { }

performSearch(searchQuery: string) {
  this.context.onSearchFound.next(searchQuery);
}
```